# Change the 2 colors on this Lottie File using Flutter

Tags: json, flutter, colors, lottie

I have a Lottie file, and it has 2 colors, black and green. All my lottie files are from Flaticon.

I want to use Flutter to change the color of the lottie file, how would I do that in Flutter?

This is how I put it in my Flutter code:

```dart
Lottie.asset(
  iconPath,
  animate: true,
  width: 60)
```

This is my lottie file:

```json
{"v":"4.8.0","meta":{"g":"LottieFiles AE 3.3.6","a":"","k":"","d":"","tc":""},"fr":25,"ip":0,"op":48,"w":500,"h":500,"nm":"02 airplane advertising","ddd":0,"assets":[],"layers":[{"ddd":0,"ind":1,"ty":3,"nm":"Main Stroke width - Color Ctrl","parent":5,"sr":1,"ks":{"o":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":11},"r":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":10},"p":{"a":0,"k":[0,0,0],"ix":2},"a":{"a":0,"k":[50,50,0],"ix":1},"s":{"a":0,"k":[100,100,100],"ix":6}},"ao":0,"ef":[{"ty":5,"nm":"Stroke width","np":3,"mn":"ADBE Slider Control","ix":1,"en":1,"ef":[{"ty":0,"nm":"Slider","mn":"ADBE Slider Control-0001","ix":1,"v":{"a":0,"k":16,"ix":1}}]}],"ip":0,"op":48,"st":-3,"bm":0},{"ddd":0,"ind":2,"ty":4,"nm":"Line","parent":4,"sr":1,"ks":{"o":{"a":0,"k":100,"ix":11},"r":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":10},"p":{"a":0,"k":[221.3,227.232,0],"ix":2},"a":{"a":0,"k":[0,0,0],"ix":1},"s":{"a":0,"k":[100,100,100],"ix":6}},"ao":0,"shapes":[{"ty":"gr","it":[{"ind":0,"ty":"sh","ix":1,"ks":{"a":0,"k":{"i":[[0,0],[0,0]],"o":[[0,0],[0,0]],"v":[[55,-174],[-54.25,-64.75]],"c":false},"ix":2},"nm":"Path 1","mn":"ADBE Vector Shape - Group","hd":false},{"ty":"st","c":{"a":0,"k":[0.20000001496,0.800000059838,0.800000059838,1],"ix":3,"x":"var $bm_rt;\n$bm_rt = thisComp.layer('Main Stroke width - Color Ctrl').effect('Highlight')('Color');"},"o":{"a":0,"k":100,"ix":4},"w":{"a":0,"k":16,"ix":5,"x":"var $bm_rt;\n$bm_rt = thisComp.layer('Main Stroke width - Color Ctrl').effect('Stroke width')('Slider');"},"lc":2,"lj":2,"bm":0,"nm":"Stroke 1","mn":"ADBE Vector Graphic - Stroke","hd":false},{"ty":"tr","p":{"a":0,"k":[0,0],"ix":2},"a":{"a":0,"k":[0,0],"ix":1},"s":{"a":0,"k":[100,100],"ix":3},"r":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":6},"o":{"a":0,"k":100,"ix":7},"sk":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":4},"sa":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":5},"nm":"Transform"}],"nm":"Shape 1","np":2,"cix":2,"bm":0,"ix":1,"mn":"ADBE Vector Group","hd":false},{"ty":"tm","s":{"a":1,"k":[{"i":{"x":[0.44],"y":[1]},"o":{"x":[0.56],"y":[0]},"t":18,"s":[0]},{"t":26,"s":[100]}],"ix":1},"e":{"a":1,"k":[{"i":{"x":[0.44],"y":[1]},"o":{"x":[0.56],"y":[0]},"t":14,"s":[0]},{"t":22,"s":[100]}],"ix":2},"o":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":3},"m":1,"ix":2,"nm":"Trim Paths 1","mn":"ADBE Vector Filter - Trim","hd":false}],"ip":0,"op":48,"st":0,"bm":0},{"ddd":0,"ind":3,"ty":4,"nm":"Line 2","parent":4,"sr":1,"ks":{"o":{"a":0,"k":100,"ix":11},"r":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":10},"p":{"a":0,"k":[374.8,313.732,0],"ix":2},"a":{"a":0,"k":[0,0,0],"ix":1},"s":{"a":0,"k":[100,100,100],"ix":6}},"ao":0,"shapes":[{"ty":"gr","it":[{"ind":0,"ty":"sh","ix":1,"ks":{"a":0,"k":{"i":[[0,0],[0,0]],"o":[[0,0],[0,0]],"v":[[55,-174],[-54.25,-64.75]],"c":false},"ix":2},"nm":"Path 1","mn":"ADBE Vector Shape - Group","hd":false},{"ty":"st","c":{"a":0,"k":[0.20000001496,0.800000059838,0.800000059838,1],"ix":3,"x":"var $bm_rt;\n$bm_rt = thisComp.layer('Main Stroke width - Color Ctrl').effect('Highlight')('Color');"},"o":{"a":0,"k":100,"ix":4},"w":{"a":0,"k":16,"ix":5,"x":"var $bm_rt;\n$bm_rt = thisComp.layer('Main Stroke width - Color Ctrl').effect('Stroke width')('Slider');"},"lc":2,"lj":2,"bm":0,"nm":"Stroke 1","mn":"ADBE Vector Graphic - Stroke","hd":false},{"ty":"tr","p":{"a":0,"k":[0,0],"ix":2},"a":{"a":0,"k":[0,0],"ix":1},"s":{"a":0,"k":[100,100],"ix":3},"r":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":6},"o":{"a":0,"k":100,"ix":7},"sk":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":4},"sa":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":5},"nm":"Transform"}],"nm":"Shape 1","np":2,"cix":2,"bm":0,"ix":1,"mn":"ADBE Vector Group","hd":false},{"ty":"tm","s":{"a":1,"k":[{"i":{"x":[0.44],"y":[1]},"o":{"x":[0.56],"y":[0]},"t":29,"s":[0]},{"t":37,"s":[100]}],"ix":1},"e":{"a":1,"k":[{"i":{"x":[0.44],"y":[1]},"o":{"x":[0.56],"y":[0]},"t":25,"s":[0]},{"t":33,"s":[100]}],"ix":2},"o":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":3},"m":1,"ix":2,"nm":"Trim Paths 1","mn":"ADBE Vector Filter - Trim","hd":false}],"ip":0,"op":48,"st":0,"bm":0},{"ddd":0,"ind":4,"ty":4,"nm":"Airplane","sr":1,"ks":{"o":{"a":0,"k":100,"ix":11},"r":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":10},"p":{"a":1,"k":[{"i":{"x":0.51,"y":1},"o":{"x":0.49,"y":0},"t":4,"s":[252.966,247.034,0],"to":[0,0,0],"ti":[0,0,0]},{"i":{"x":0.51,"y":1},"o":{"x":0.49,"y":0},"t":24,"s":[289.966,209.034,0],"to":[0,0,0],"ti":[0,0,0]},{"t":45,"s":[252.966,247.034,0]}],"ix":2},"a":{"a":0,"k":[224.266,224.266,0],"ix":1},"s":{"a":0,"k":[100,100,100],"ix":6}},"ao":0,"shapes":[{"ty":"gr","it":[{"ind":0,"ty":"sh","ix":1,"ks":{"a":0,"k":{"i":[[0,0],[0,0],[19.977,19.977],[18.025,-21.755],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0]],"o":[[0,0],[21.755,-18.026],[-19.978,-19.978],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0]],"v":[[-11.911,58.697],[109.046,-41.524],[112.358,-112.358],[41.524,-109.045],[-58.697,11.912],[-100.42,-5.969],[-132.336,25.947],[-57.864,57.864],[-25.948,132.336],[5.969,100.419]],"c":true},"ix":2},"nm":"Path 1","mn":"ADBE Vector Shape - Group","hd":false},{"ty":"st","c":{"a":0,"k":[0,0,0,1],"ix":3,"x":"var $bm_rt;\n$bm_rt = thisComp.layer('Main Stroke width - Color Ctrl').effect('Base Color')('Color');"},"o":{"a":0,"k":100,"ix":4},"w":{"a":0,"k":16,"ix":5,"x":"var $bm_rt;\n$bm_rt = thisComp.layer('Main Stroke width - Color Ctrl').effect('Stroke width')('Slider');"},"lc":2,"lj":2,"bm":0,"nm":"Stroke 1","mn":"ADBE Vector Graphic - Stroke","hd":false},{"ty":"tr","p":{"a":0,"k":[276.196,172.336],"ix":2},"a":{"a":0,"k":[0,0],"ix":1},"s":{"a":0,"k":[100,100],"ix":3},"r":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":6},"o":{"a":0,"k":100,"ix":7},"sk":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":4},"sa":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":5},"nm":"Transform"}],"nm":"Group 1","np":2,"cix":2,"bm":0,"ix":1,"mn":"ADBE Vector Group","hd":false},{"ty":"gr","it":[{"ind":0,"ty":"sh","ix":1,"ks":{"a":1,"k":[{"i":{"x":0.44,"y":1},"o":{"x":0.56,"y":0},"t":4,"s":[{"i":[[0,0],[0,0]],"o":[[0,0],[0,0]],"v":[[10.639,-10.639],[-10.639,10.639]],"c":false}]},{"i":{"x":0.44,"y":1},"o":{"x":0.56,"y":0},"t":19,"s":[{"i":[[0,0],[0,0]],"o":[[0,0],[0,0]],"v":[[-12.13,12.13],[-51.87,51.87]],"c":false}]},{"i":{"x":0.44,"y":1},"o":{"x":0.56,"y":0},"t":34,"s":[{"i":[[0,0],[0,0]],"o":[[0,0],[0,0]],"v":[[20.639,-20.639],[-0.639,0.639]],"c":false}]},{"t":46,"s":[{"i":[[0,0],[0,0]],"o":[[0,0],[0,0]],"v":[[10.639,-10.639],[-10.639,10.639]],"c":false}]}],"ix":2},"nm":"Path 1","mn":"ADBE Vector Shape - Group","hd":false},{"ty":"st","c":{"a":0,"k":[0.20000001496,0.800000059838,0.800000059838,1],"ix":3,"x":"var $bm_rt;\n$bm_rt = thisComp.layer('Main Stroke width - Color Ctrl').effect('Highlight')('Color');"},"o":{"a":0,"k":100,"ix":4},"w":{"a":0,"k":16,"ix":5,"x":"var $bm_rt;\n$bm_rt = thisComp.layer('Main Stroke width - Color Ctrl').effect('Stroke width')('Slider');"},"lc":2,"lj":2,"bm":0,"nm":"Stroke 1","mn":"ADBE Vector Graphic - Stroke","hd":false},{"ty":"tr","p":{"a":0,"k":[130.43,318.102],"ix":2},"a":{"a":0,"k":[0,0],"ix":1},"s":{"a":0,"k":[100,100],"ix":3},"r":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":6},"o":{"a":0,"k":100,"ix":7},"sk":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":4},"sa":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":5},"nm":"Transform"}],"nm":"Group 2","np":2,"cix":2,"bm":0,"ix":2,"mn":"ADBE Vector Group","hd":false},{"ty":"gr","it":[{"ind":0,"ty":"sh","ix":1,"ks":{"a":1,"k":[{"i":{"x":0.44,"y":1},"o":{"x":0.56,"y":0},"t":4,"s":[{"i":[[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0]],"o":[[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0]],"v":[[79.792,-26.598],[26.597,-79.791],[-79.792,26.597],[-31.917,31.917],[-26.598,79.792]],"c":true}]},{"i":{"x":0.44,"y":1},"o":{"x":0.56,"y":0},"t":19,"s":[{"i":[[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0]],"o":[[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0]],"v":[[47.792,5.403],[-5.403,-47.791],[-111.792,58.597],[-63.917,63.917],[-58.598,111.792]],"c":true}]},{"i":{"x":0.44,"y":1},"o":{"x":0.56,"y":0},"t":34,"s":[{"i":[[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0]],"o":[[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0]],"v":[[89.792,-36.598],[36.597,-89.791],[-69.792,16.597],[-21.917,21.917],[-16.598,69.792]],"c":true}]},{"t":46,"s":[{"i":[[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0]],"o":[[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0]],"v":[[79.792,-26.598],[26.597,-79.791],[-79.792,26.597],[-31.917,31.917],[-26.598,79.792]],"c":true}]}],"ix":2},"nm":"Path 1","mn":"ADBE Vector Shape - Group","hd":false},{"ty":"st","c":{"a":0,"k":[0.20000001496,0.800000059838,0.800000059838,1],"ix":3,"x":"var $bm_rt;\n$bm_rt = thisComp.layer('Main Stroke width - Color Ctrl').effect('Highlight')('Color');"},"o":{"a":0,"k":100,"ix":4},"w":{"a":0,"k":16,"ix":5,"x":"var $bm_rt;\n$bm_rt = thisComp.layer('Main Stroke width - Color Ctrl').effect('Stroke width')('Slider');"},"lc":2,"lj":2,"bm":0,"nm":"Stroke 1","mn":"ADBE Vector Graphic - Stroke","hd":false},{"ty":"tr","p":{"a":0,"k":[119.791,328.741],"ix":2},"a":{"a":0,"k":[0,0],"ix":1},"s":{"a":0,"k":[100,100],"ix":3},"r":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":6},"o":{"a":0,"k":100,"ix":7},"sk":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":4},"sa":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":5},"nm":"Transform"}],"nm":"Group 3","np":2,"cix":2,"bm":0,"ix":3,"mn":"ADBE Vector Group","hd":false},{"ty":"gr","it":[{"ind":0,"ty":"sh","ix":1,"ks":{"a":1,"k":[{"i":{"x":0.44,"y":1},"o":{"x":0.56,"y":0},"t":4,"s":[{"i":[[0,0],[0,0]],"o":[[0,0],[0,0]],"v":[[19.482,-19.482],[-19.482,19.482]],"c":false}]},{"i":{"x":0.44,"y":1},"o":{"x":0.56,"y":0},"t":19,"s":[{"i":[[0,0],[0,0]],"o":[[0,0],[0,0]],"v":[[19.482,-19.482],[-51.482,51.482]],"c":false}]},{"i":{"x":0.44,"y":1},"o":{"x":0.56,"y":0},"t":34,"s":[{"i":[[0,0],[0,0]],"o":[[0,0],[0,0]],"v":[[19.482,-19.482],[-9.482,9.482]],"c":false}]},{"t":46,"s":[{"i":[[0,0],[0,0]],"o":[[0,0],[0,0]],"v":[[19.482,-19.482],[-19.482,19.482]],"c":false}]}],"ix":2},"nm":"Path 1","mn":"ADBE Vector Shape - Group","hd":false},{"ty":"st","c":{"a":0,"k":[0.20000001496,0.800000059838,0.800000059838,1],"ix":3,"x":"var $bm_rt;\n$bm_rt = thisComp.layer('Main Stroke width - Color Ctrl').effect('Highlight')('Color');"},"o":{"a":0,"k":100,"ix":4},"w":{"a":0,"k":16,"ix":5,"x":"var $bm_rt;\n$bm_rt = thisComp.layer('Main Stroke width - Color Ctrl').effect('Stroke width')('Slider');"},"lc":2,"lj":2,"bm":0,"nm":"Stroke 1","mn":"ADBE Vector Graphic - Stroke","hd":false},{"ty":"tr","p":{"a":0,"k":[176.509,240.106],"ix":2},"a":{"a":0,"k":[0,0],"ix":1},"s":{"a":0,"k":[100,100],"ix":3},"r":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":6},"o":{"a":0,"k":100,"ix":7},"sk":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":4},"sa":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":5},"nm":"Transform"}],"nm":"Group 4","np":2,"cix":2,"bm":0,"ix":4,"mn":"ADBE Vector Group","hd":false},{"ty":"gr","it":[{"ind":0,"ty":"sh","ix":1,"ks":{"a":1,"k":[{"i":{"x":0.44,"y":1},"o":{"x":0.56,"y":0},"t":4,"s":[{"i":[[0,0],[0,0]],"o":[[0,0],[0,0]],"v":[[19.482,-19.482],[-19.482,19.482]],"c":false}]},{"i":{"x":0.44,"y":1},"o":{"x":0.56,"y":0},"t":19,"s":[{"i":[[0,0],[0,0]],"o":[[0,0],[0,0]],"v":[[19.482,-19.482],[-51.482,51.482]],"c":false}]},{"i":{"x":0.44,"y":1},"o":{"x":0.56,"y":0},"t":34,"s":[{"i":[[0,0],[0,0]],"o":[[0,0],[0,0]],"v":[[19.482,-19.482],[-9.482,9.482]],"c":false}]},{"t":46,"s":[{"i":[[0,0],[0,0]],"o":[[0,0],[0,0]],"v":[[19.482,-19.482],[-19.482,19.482]],"c":false}]}],"ix":2},"nm":"Path 1","mn":"ADBE Vector Shape - Group","hd":false},{"ty":"st","c":{"a":0,"k":[0.20000001496,0.800000059838,0.800000059838,1],"ix":3,"x":"var $bm_rt;\n$bm_rt = thisComp.layer('Main Stroke width - Color Ctrl').effect('Highlight')('Color');"},"o":{"a":0,"k":100,"ix":4},"w":{"a":0,"k":16,"ix":5,"x":"var $bm_rt;\n$bm_rt = thisComp.layer('Main Stroke width - Color Ctrl').effect('Stroke width')('Slider');"},"lc":2,"lj":2,"bm":0,"nm":"Stroke 1","mn":"ADBE Vector Graphic - Stroke","hd":false},{"ty":"tr","p":{"a":0,"k":[208.425,272.023],"ix":2},"a":{"a":0,"k":[0,0],"ix":1},"s":{"a":0,"k":[100,100],"ix":3},"r":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":6},"o":{"a":0,"k":100,"ix":7},"sk":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":4},"sa":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":5},"nm":"Transform"}],"nm":"Group 5","np":2,"cix":2,"bm":0,"ix":5,"mn":"ADBE Vector Group","hd":false},{"ty":"gr","it":[{"ind":0,"ty":"sh","ix":1,"ks":{"a":0,"k":{"i":[[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0]],"o":[[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0]],"v":[[56.712,-12.592],[-30.116,-33.265],[-56.713,-6.668],[18.716,33.265]],"c":false},"ix":2},"nm":"Path 1","mn":"ADBE Vector Shape - Group","hd":false},{"ty":"st","c":{"a":0,"k":[0,0,0,1],"ix":3,"x":"var $bm_rt;\n$bm_rt = thisComp.layer('Main Stroke width - Color Ctrl').effect('Base Color')('Color');"},"o":{"a":0,"k":100,"ix":4},"w":{"a":0,"k":16,"ix":5,"x":"var $bm_rt;\n$bm_rt = thisComp.layer('Main Stroke width - Color Ctrl').effect('Stroke width')('Slider');"},"lc":2,"lj":2,"bm":0,"nm":"Stroke 1","mn":"ADBE Vector Graphic - Stroke","hd":false},{"ty":"tr","p":{"a":0,"k":[237.809,103.882],"ix":2},"a":{"a":0,"k":[0,0],"ix":1},"s":{"a":0,"k":[100,100],"ix":3},"r":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":6},"o":{"a":0,"k":100,"ix":7},"sk":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":4},"sa":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":5},"nm":"Transform"}],"nm":"Group 6","np":2,"cix":2,"bm":0,"ix":6,"mn":"ADBE Vector Group","hd":false},{"ty":"gr","it":[{"ind":0,"ty":"sh","ix":1,"ks":{"a":0,"k":{"i":[[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0]],"o":[[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0]],"v":[[-33.265,-18.717],[6.668,56.712],[33.265,30.115],[12.592,-56.712]],"c":false},"ix":2},"nm":"Path 1","mn":"ADBE Vector Shape - Group","hd":false},{"ty":"st","c":{"a":0,"k":[0,0,0,1],"ix":3,"x":"var $bm_rt;\n$bm_rt = thisComp.layer('Main Stroke width - Color Ctrl').effect('Base Color')('Color');"},"o":{"a":0,"k":100,"ix":4},"w":{"a":0,"k":16,"ix":5,"x":"var $bm_rt;\n$bm_rt = thisComp.layer('Main Stroke width - Color Ctrl').effect('Stroke width')('Slider');"},"lc":2,"lj":2,"bm":0,"nm":"Stroke 1","mn":"ADBE Vector Graphic - Stroke","hd":false},{"ty":"tr","p":{"a":0,"k":[344.65,210.724],"ix":2},"a":{"a":0,"k":[0,0],"ix":1},"s":{"a":0,"k":[100,100],"ix":3},"r":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":6},"o":{"a":0,"k":100,"ix":7},"sk":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":4},"sa":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":5},"nm":"Transform"}],"nm":"Group 7","np":2,"cix":2,"bm":0,"ix":7,"mn":"ADBE Vector Group","hd":false}],"ip":0,"op":48,"st":0,"bm":0},{"ddd":0,"ind":5,"ty":3,"nm":"Zero | troke width - Color Ctrl","sr":1,"ks":{"o":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":11},"r":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":10},"p":{"a":0,"k":[250,250,0],"ix":2},"a":{"a":0,"k":[0,0,0],"ix":1},"s":{"a":0,"k":[100,100,100],"ix":6}},"ao":0,"ip":0,"op":48,"st":0,"bm":0}],"markers":[]}
```

Any help would be appreciated!